# Animated fantasy movie from recent years about heroine and troll

Tags: story-identification, movie

A movie from 2010 onward. I think this may be something fairly well known (one of the later Shreks for example). This may be the intro to the movie or a dream sequence as I think it's not part of the main plot.

A heroine tames or defeats a troll in a forest. The troll may have defeated a knight or two before. He chases her into a tree house? Peers into it from the outside... etc.

I dimly recall later parts of the plot, the troll may be on her side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Enchanted](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0461770/)* from 2007.

A troll peers in at Giselle in her treehouse. The start of the film is a cartoon (unlike the rest of the film which is largely live-action), lending a *Disneyesque* quality to the opening scenes.

[image]